# Can I auto-hide the status text in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox

Now that Firefox 4 has eliminated the status bar, the status text is in a little box in the corner. However, this box never actually disappears. It just moves out of the way to the other corner when you mouse over it. Is it possible to make it auto-hide after a short delay, like Chrome's does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the name and desctiption, the [Status-4-Evar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/status-4-evar/) extension has auto-hide as one of its options.